Why would GCC behave differently depending on if it's called with the full path or via the PATH environment variable?
I got an error when running some code with (MinGW) GCC 14.2.0 on MSYS. I then removed GCC from PATH and called it directly, via its absolute path, and the error disappears. Why could this happen?
Running which i686-w64-mingw32-gcc produces the result I expect. I've also cleared and rebuilt the standard library modules I'm using. Could it be that GCC locates other files differently depending on PATH?

and which gcc, which cpp ?

which gcc etc. points to the wrong compiler, however I'm explicitly calling the full compiler name, i686-w64-mingw32-gcc. Do you think certain components just call gcc and friends?

I've encountered very strange errors when some tool bundled its own toolchain and there was more than one gcc in my path.

Hmm, that's worrying. As I wish to cross compile multiple targets in the same toolchain call

gcc is a collection of programs, so it will call probably other programs and it will go to the wrong one

Is there a known procedure to e.g. use the same makefile to call multiple environments that only know about a single compiler?

Might be best for another SO question, as I suppose it's getting slightly off-topic If someone could kindly post an answer mentioning the above I'll accept it (in the morning - it's getting late here)

Apparently not. My question got downvoted, so I guess it's just not appropriate for SO? Can't really say

It should definitely not be the case that the gcc front-end will invoke the wrong backend.  The backends are stored in special directories in the installation which are NOT on your PATH (or at least should not be) and the front-end looks for them with relative pathnames, not on the PATH at all.  I don't think that comment is correct, unless MinGW does something super-bizarre with their install of GCC.

Try compiling with gcc -v, in both the working and broken configurations, and diffing the results. This will print out a verbose listing of the subcommands invoked, as well as GCC configuration information, and might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Never add gcc build tools to the global system PATH environment variable. It can really get you in trouble, especially when you have multiple similar tools on your system (MSYS2, Cygwin, winlibs, ...). Also it cause issues picking up DLLs from the wrong place. Those kind of issues can be really hard to troubleshoot.
